# c# array multidimensional or jagged

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm drawing a 3x3 grid of squares for a 2D game map.

I want to create an array that has a row and column position and for each row and column position, it has 4 0's or 1's representing if a wall will be drawn on that edge of the square.

I want to create this array:

```
        int [,][,,,] Boxes = {{0,0}, {1,0,0,1},
          {1,0}, {1,0,1,0},
          {0,1}, {0,0,0,1}, 
          {1,1}, {1,1,1,0}, 
          {2,0}, {1,1,0,0},
          {2,1}, {0,0,0,1}, 
          {3,1}, {1,0,1,0}, 
          {0,2}, {0,0,1,1}, 
          {1,2}, {1,0,1,0}, 
          {2,2}, {0,1,1,0}};
```

However, it seems to be not correct.

I have also tried this:

```
        int [][] Boxes = new int [2][4] 
        Boxes = {{0,0}, {1,0,0,1},
          {1,0}, {1,0,1,0},
          {0,1}, {0,0,0,1}, 
          {1,1}, {1,1,1,0}, 
          {2,0}, {1,1,0,0},
          {2,1}, {0,0,0,1}, 
          {3,1}, {1,0,1,0}, 
          {0,2}, {0,0,1,1}, 
          {1,2}, {1,0,1,0}, 
          {2,2}, {0,1,1,0}};
```

Is it clear, the type of array i am trying to make?

How would i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Chances are this would be much, much clearer and not awful design if you create a `Position` object that has an internal `row`, `column`, and `Walls`. Then your problem simplifies to an array of `Position` that you iterate over.

Comment: Have you tried the type `int [2, 4]`?

Comment: Thanks. I actually want the array to be pictureBoxes, to be able to insert a picture, but also draw a line over the edge of the square representing a wall. I originally had this: 'PictureBox[,] Boxes = new PictureBox[4,4];' and it did draw the grid and used the row and column and box width to figure out where to draw each square. I will attempt the object way you have suggested. Would i do 'PictureBox[0,0].row = 1;' 'PictureBox[0,0].walls = {1,0,0,1};'?

Comment: There's no need for storing position when working with 2D maps, because array[X,Y] serve the same purpose. Make your life easier and use properly named objects: class Cell { bool LeftWall; bool TopWall; bool RightWall; bool BottomWall } var map = new Cell[3,3]; Simply because when you want to extend this, e.g. change floor colouring, all you need to do is add another property: "int FloorColour".

Comment: @MikeTrusov Thanks! Looking into this design

Comment: @MikeTrusov If you would like to take a look at my implementation and new question that would be very appreciated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325291/implementing-a-2d-map?noredirect=1#comment26895491_18325291 Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem with your first approach is that int[,][,,,] is a two dimensional array of four dimensional arrays. [,] refers to an array of the form {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, no of the form {0, 0}. The commas indicate the number of *dimensions*, not the number of *elements*.

Your second approach is much closer. You are creating an array of the correct dimensions, but you can't initialize arrays within array inline like that. It would look more like this:

```
int [][] Boxes = new int[][] {
      new int[] {1,0}, new int[] {1,0,1,0},
      new int[] {0,1}, new int[] {0,0,0,1}, 
      new int[] {1,1}, new int[] {1,1,1,0}, 
      new int[] {2,0}, new int[] {1,1,0,0},
      new int[] {2,1}, new int[] {0,0,0,1}, 
      new int[] {3,1}, new int[] {1,0,1,0}, 
      new int[] {0,2}, new int[] {0,0,1,1}, 
      new int[] {1,2}, new int[] {1,0,1,0}, 
      new int[] {2,2}, new int[] {0,1,1,0}};
```

which is, quite frankly, hideous.

One thing that stands out here is that you wrote `new int [2][4]`. [2][4] doesn't refer to an array of size 2 followed by an array of size 4. It refers to an array of size two of arrays of size 4, and important distinction. Looks into the difference between dimensions and length, as it appears to be the main problem you're having in getting your code to work.

As others have mentioned, this design isn't making good use of the tools you have. Your code could be much clearly if you used objects to encapsulate this data, instead of putting multiple types of data in the same array. This gets confusing and is very error prone.

Comment: Thanks, i may have to start a new question about how i would use objects with properties, but i will try it myself and see how i go. I would prefer each square to be a picture box object so i can insert a picture tile, and then give that picturebox object an array {x,x,x,x} representing walls to be drawn or not drawn. And i guess give it a column and row. Does this sound feasible?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your plan is, but based off my interpretation of it, it seems feasible. The most recent comment on your question suggests something better, though.

Comment: I am not sure how to reference an item on this array once i have done this. It doesnt let me say Boxes[0,0] anymore because it is not expecting a comma

Comment: Thanks, what comment is that? I am at this stage trying to implement both your method of arrays, and the method above this, and see in which one i can successfully call items from the array. Then i will think about a better design

Comment: Mike Trusov's comment has useful advice.

Comment: Thanks it is good advice. I understand arrays better now too.

Comment: If you would like to take a look at my new implementation and question that would be very appraciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325291/implementing-a-2d-map?noredirect=1#comment26895491_18325291 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
int[,][] boxes = new int[3,3][];
boxes[0,1] = new [] { 0, 0, 0, 1};
boxes[1,0] = new [] { 1, 0, 1, 0};
// .. etc.
```

But as mentioned in the comments, you might want to reconsider your design. Creating some classes would make things clearer.