# Implementing a 2D Map

Tags: c#, dictionary

I posted a Q. earlier about arrays and the replies lead me to change my game design. I'm building a 2D game map from tiles (Cells). I need to add a pen line to some cells, representing a wall you cannot pass through. This pen line is represented by Cell.TopWall, Cell.BottomWall etc etc of type boolean as shown in my code. This is my whole app so far. It draws the grid without the pen lines for walls. Take note of commented out code where i have tried different things like stating where the walls go with an array of 0's (no wall) and 1's (walls). My question is, can i get a hint on how to implement the walls where i would like? I hope i have shared enough information about my app. Thanks

Cell.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Map
{
    public class Cell : PictureBox
    {
        bool LeftWall; 
        bool TopWall; 
        bool RightWall;
        bool BottomWall;
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Map
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Array of tiles
        /// </summary>
        //PictureBox[,] Boxes = new PictureBox[4,4];
        Cell[,] Map = new Cell[4,4];

        /*int [][] Boxes = new int[][] {
      new int[] {0,0}, new int[] {1,0,0,1},
      new int[] {1,0}, new int[] {1,0,1,0},
      new int[] {0,1}, new int[] {0,0,0,1}, 
      new int[] {1,1}, new int[] {1,1,1,0}, 
      new int[] {2,0}, new int[] {1,1,0,0},
      new int[] {2,1}, new int[] {0,0,0,1}, 
      new int[] {3,1}, new int[] {1,0,1,0}, 
      new int[] {0,2}, new int[] {0,0,1,1}, 
      new int[] {1,2}, new int[] {1,0,1,0}, 
      new int[] {2,2}, new int[] {0,1,1,0}};*/

        #region Runtime load
        /// <summary>
        /// Build the map when window is loaded
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BuildMap();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Build grid
        /// <summary>
        /// Draw every tile on the map
        /// </summary>
        public void BuildMap()
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                {
                    DrawBox(row, column);
                }
            }
            //draw the exit box
            DrawBox(1, 3);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Draw
        /// <summary>
        /// Draw one tile
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="row"></param>
        /// <param name="column"></param>
        public void DrawBox(int row, int column)
        {
            Map[row, column] = new Cell();
            Map[row, column].Height = 100;
            Map[row, column].Width = 100;
            Map[row, column].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            Map[row, column].BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
            Map[row, column].Location = new Point((Map[row, column].Width * column), (Map[row, column].Height * row));
            this.Controls.Add(Map[row, column]);

            System.Drawing.Pen myPen;
            myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();


            //formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 200, 200);
            //myPen.Dispose();
            //formGraphics.Dispose();
        }
        #endregion
    }


}
```

Comment: What is `Map`? Where is that defined? What isn't working?

Comment: Forget  winforms.  It's too old. You can happily do this in WPF with a ListBox and some DataTemplates.

Comment: Map is an array of cells. a cell is an object from class Cell that inherits from PictureBox. It all works fine, but i have not implemented the walls (a pen line on the edge of a cell that a player cannot pass through) (represented by Cell.Topwall = false or true etc. Thanks

Comment: Map is defined in Form1.cs, as the name of the array of cells. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using PictureBoxes, you could draw on form's canvas itself, to do that you implement the OnPaint event. In that event you will get access to the graphics object, and then you can iterate through your cells and render them. To force repaint you call this.Invalidate()

Comment: @MikeTrusov Thanks. I planned to do that over top of the PictureBoxes. I thought it would look more professional with images of a wood floor etc in the PictureBoxes. I'm not sure if it's possible though. It is not hugely important. The main part is the drawing lines. How will i state what tile has what wall properties? I want them to have the properties shown in the Boxes array of 1's and 0's. I was planning on reading files of arrays like that then implementing the walls automatically. Firstly i just want to draw one map with walls. Thanks

Comment: var g = event.Graphics; for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) { for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++) { var cell = map[x,y]; if (cell.LeftWall) g.DrawLine(pen, x * cellWidth, y * CellHeight, x * cellWidth, (y + 1) * cellHeight); /* do other walls similarly*/ g.DrawImage(x * cellWidth, y * cellHeight, /* draw floor image loaded from file*/); } }

Comment: @MikeTrusov Thanks, that is a big help for when i get to that stage, however i have not set leftwall to true or false yet, for each cell, and that is what i am struggling with. I started doing that with the array that is commented out. Maybe i have to do Map[0,0].leftWall = true...But that will be a lot more code than the original array of 0's and 1's i had. And i'm not sure if that is easy to make different maps, or read maps from a text file. Those things are not imperative but i think it makes it more scalable if it can make more maps easily.

Comment: Add a constructor or two, so you can do "map[x,y] = new Cell(false, false, false, false);" and/or "new Cell("0,0,0,1,12");" Ideally you want to save/load map using files rather than hard-coded arrays. Your file can still look like an array, i.e. "0,1,0,0,12;0,1,0,0,12;..." (wall, wall, wall, wall, floor) then you load it line-by-line, split lines on semi-color to get cell data, then split on comma to get walls and floor values.

Comment: @MikeTrusov Thank you that is great! I will implement that now. Is the 5th Cell argument representing an image? the 12 you inserted in the parenthesis. I know it is floor, i'm just wondering if it will represent an image, or what. I never thought of having a floor argument. Thanks very much.

Comment: image id, then when you render you can do switch(cell.Floor) case 0: /* draw wood */ break; case 1: /*draw stone*/ break; etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35838/discussion-between-user2602079-and-mike-trusov)